# Android Google Map coordinate

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-extensions

Currently doing a simple app that contain google map. and i would like to link to next activity when the user click on a designed coordinate but it is not working and there is no error, please help me

```
double latitude = 1.34503109;

    double longitude = 103.94008398;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Selecting_Bus.this,
                    Activity_Bus_Selected.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have markers set up in your map and when user clicks on a marker you start another activity. The following code should work (in `SupportMapFragment`):

```
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // do the thing!
    return true;
  }
});
```

If you don't have markers and want to listen for a certain location click use this instead:

```
getMap().setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    // do the thing!
  }
});
```

In this case you probably want to start the activity when the user clicks "close enough" to a certain location. I use this library http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/ which contains method

```
SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(LatLng from, LatLng to)
```

which returns distance between two `LatLng`s in meters.

**EDIT Example:**

First you define where the user has to click and which activity does that particular click launch:

```
private static final HashMap<LatLng, Class<? extends Activity>> sTargets = new HashMap();

static {
    sTargets.put(new LatLng(34.0204989,-118.4117325), LosAngelesActivity.class);
    sTargets.put(new LatLng(42.755942,-75.8092041), NewYorkActivity.class);
    sTargets.put(new LatLng(42.352711,-83.099205), DetroitActivity.class);
}

private static final int RANGE_METERS = 200 * 1000; // 200 km range
```

Then when the user clicks on the map, you compute distance to each point. If it fits, you launch the activity.

```
getMap().setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng input) {
        for(Map.Entry<LatLng,<? extends Activity>> entry : sTargets.entrySet()) {
            LatLng ll = entry.getKey();
            boolean inRange = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(input, ll) < RANGE_METERS;
            if (inRange) {
                Class<? extends Activity> cls = entry.getValue();
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), cls);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
                break; // stop calculating after first result
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to mark correct answer. Good luck with your apps!

Comment: Which coordinates? [How to add markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)

Comment: sorry for troubling, what i actually meant is i input a destination ( coordinates) and when user click the location, it will link them to a page

Comment: Oh, I thought you had them hardcoded in an array or got them some other way beforehand.

Comment: I have no idea where your data comes from or what it represents so it's impossible for me to tell you how to store it. Please open another question if you need help with that.

Comment: i tried this way but it could not work 
    double latitude = 1.34503109;

  double longitude = 103.94008398;

  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Selecting_Bus.this,
      Activity_Bus_Selected.class);
    startActivity(i);

   }
  });